# Entgegengesetzt als Adjektiv

Tags: word-usage

Zum ersten mal habe ich das Adjektiv "entgegengesetzt" an einer Haltestelle gesehen. Da stand so etwas wie "Bushaltestelle befindet sich 100 Meter in entgegengesetzter Richtung". Seitdem versuche ich das Adjektiv in verschiedenen Kontexten zu nutzen.
Wären richtig folgende Sätze?

1. In U-Bahn, wenn jemand in Wagen einsteigen will und fragt, ob der Zug Richtung XY hinfährt:

   > Sie <s>sollen</s> müssen in entgegengesetzter/entegegengesetzte Richtung fahren
2. Wenn ich früher total andere Info von einem anderen Mitarbeiter bekommen habe:

   > Ich habe von Ihrer Kollegin das entgegengesetzte gehört

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort wird für Richtungen verwendet. Wenn ich so etwas an einer Haltestelle sehe, bedeutet das "gehe über die Straße und dann 100m entgegen der Richtung aus der die Autos auf dieser Straßenseite (wo das Schild ist) kommen". 
1. Ginge schon, ich würde aber sagen: Sie müssen in entgegengesetzter Richtung fahren. (müssen um auszudrücken "wenn Sie Ihr Ziel erreichen wollen")
2. Ich habe von Ihrer Kollegin das Gegenteil gehört.

Comment: cool danke, mit dem Gegenteil habe ich auch mehrmals gehört, hört sich gewohnt an